# TypeDef with three parameters

Tags: c

I'm reading the mimikatz source code and was struggling to understand this.

I see KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE is an alias for the struct, what does  *PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE mean?

```
typedef struct _KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE
{
    HANDLE hFileMapping;
    LPVOID pMapViewOfFile;
    PBYTE pStartOf;
    PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_KEY_NAMED pRootNamedKey;
} KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE, *PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE;
```

Comment: its a pointer to a struct

Comment: Never typedef pointers\

Comment: And `_KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE` is a [reserved identifier](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3)

Comment: This is a practice that is wide-spread in the Windows SDK.  It doesn't just declare the type of the struct but also of a pointer to the struct.  Same name as the struct type, but starting with P.  What they were thinking has never been obvious to me, perhaps a Hungarian habit.  Hungarian doesn't have a lot of fans.  There is no obligation to use it, most programmers just use KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE* in their own declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typedef` turns a normal declaration/definition into a definition of one or more type aliases.

Therefore whereas

```
struct _KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE{ ... } 
      KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE, *PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE;
```

(no `typedef` there) would declare `KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE` as variable of type `struct _KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE` and `PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE` as a pointer to an object of type `struct _KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE`,

with the `typedef` it makes `KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE` an alias of type `struct _KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE` and `PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE` an alias of type `struct _KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE*`.

(aliases of the types the variables the declared variables had in the `typedef`-less version)

**Side note:** Tagging the struct with a name starting with `_` and especially `_` and a capital letter is a (common) bad practice. Those names are reserved. (`_[a-z0-9]` names are reserved at filescope & in the tag namespace, `_[A-Z_]` names at all scopes.) I'd keep it simple and just reuse the `typedef` name for the tag (`struct KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE`).

Comment: In the tag name space, all identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved, not just those followed by a capital letter or and underscore.

Answer (score 7):

If you say

```
const int a, b;
```

you're declaring two variables of type `const int`.

If you say

```
const int i, *p;
```

you're declaring two variables, one of type `const int` and one of type "pointer to `const int`".

And in a perfectly analogous, way, if you say

```
typedef struct { … } KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE, *PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE;
```

you're declaring two typedefs, one for type struct, and one for type pointer-to-that-struct.

So if you later say

```
PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE kmrhp;
```

it would declare `kmrhp` as a pointer, exactly as if you had said

```
KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE *kmrhp;
```

---

Addendum: And then one way pointer typedefs start getting more interesting is that if you say

```
PKULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE p1, p2;
```

it declares *two* pointers, as if you had said

```
KULL_M_REGISTRY_HIVE_HANDLE *p1, *p2;
```